# How to find possible closed-form-formula for a given decimal expansion online?

Tags: closed-form, decimal-expansion

What mathematical program or library can guess formula for decimal fraction? For example, for number 2.414213562373095 right guess is 1 + $\sqrt 2$. Are there such tools online? I cannot find one.

Comment: Wolfram alpha is very good for this : Just enter a decimal expansion to get various possible closed forms!

Comment: @S.C.B. But 2.414213562373095 is.

Comment: But do not expect miracles! If you enter the decimal expansion of $\large \frac{\pi^3+e^3-\sqrt{7}}{\pi^5-e^7+\sqrt{11}}$ , you won't get your expression as a closed form. But for numbers satisfying linear or algebraic dependences with great accuracy , such as in the example, it will work very well.

Comment: For the case, you also accept offline tools, I suggest the free PARI/GP-calculator. It can determine algebraic and linear dependencies.

Comment: Using continued fractions, you can find very good rational approximations even with a table calculator. For example , $\pi$ is very close to $\frac{355}{113}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using keywords from Peter's comment ("closed form by decimal expansion") I found [Inverse Symbolic Calculator](https://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html)
Also see [Sympy number identification](https://omz-software.com/pythonista/sympy/modules/mpmath/identification.html)

Comment: I did not know that this calculator still/again exists, but it is also very good and powerful.

Comment: Both links are now dead.

Comment: I fixed both links.